# Ubuntu unable to use wifi but connected

Tags: networking

I recently attempted to set up a static IP on my Ubuntu, following a tutorial from howtoforge. After I followed the instructions, I could not access internet. On instinct, I checked my wifi list and saw that Ethernet had a connection. I turned it off, and I got wifi back. I am not sure if the above ties in to this but I included it just in case.

The next day I cannot access internet again, there are no connections to Ethernet, and when I ping 8.8.8.8 I get the error "From 192.168.1.(not sure if safe to put this bit out, I am a noob) icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable" I would paste my if config but I am posting this from my phone.

If anyone can help, I would appreciate it so much! Thank you!
Os: Ubuntu 16.04
Router: Linksys

Comment: The router likely gives a IP dynamically (using DHCP), so using static IP may not work. I suggest you revert to previous settings, unless you have strong reason not to.

Comment: It is entirely safe to set a static IP address as long as it's outside the DHCP pool used in the router so as to avoid collisions. We'd like to see what your configuration is; IP address, netmask, gateway and the all important DNS nameserver. By the way, 192.168.1.xxx is a private IP address; half the world, including me, uses the same. It is not a security risk to disclose it.

Comment: Ok, my first my IP is 192.168.1.114, and second, I reset it and internet works fine. BUT, if you guys/gals know how to fix this and it will allow me to still have a static IP, I will definitely try it!

Comment: @chili555 My wlan0 section of ifconfig says: inet addr:192.168.1.114  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you edit connections in Network Manager to set a static IP address. It is important that the address selected be outside the DHCP pool used in the router. There is one correct way to do this. It is to check the configuration pages of the router to check. http://www.mindspacesolutions.com/assets/images/D-Link_Router_Config_-_DHCP.jpg In this example, the pool for DHCP is from 10.1.1.2 to 10.1.1.32 and so we'd recommend a static IP address of 10.1.1.33 or above; say, 10.1.1.100. Of course, your details will be very different.

The second method is to guess. I gather that, when you switched back to DHCP, the router assigned 192.168.1.114. Compare this to other devices on the same network; phones, iPads, Windows computers, etc. I'd guess that they are all in the x.110, x.111, x.112, etc. range. Therefore, if we were to guess a static IP, we might guess 192.168.1.200.

Also, compare the gateway address and DNS nameserver addresses on other devices on the network.

Next, fill in the details in Network Manager like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hvi2cTMmTq0 Of course, your details will be different.

Save and close. Reboot and test:

```
ifconfig
```

Did you get the desired address?

```
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

If you get ping returns, you are all set.